# using regex on scrapy item loader

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to figure out how to use regex with scrapy item loaders.
I've tried to use a lambda function with split() and got the following error.
Split cannot be defined. You can see the function is commented out in the item loader class.

What I'm trying to do is remove all the text before the date including the "/"
of the date item. Date item being the url that I've just parsed

"https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"

How do I use regex with scrapy item loaders?
Can I pass in the regex to the item loader or do I have to process it at the spider?

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapejs.items import SofascoreItemLoader
from scrapy import Spider

import json
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jsscraper"

    start_urls = ["https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"]


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                            callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='render.html',
                            args={'wait': 1.5})



    def parse(self, response):
           for row in response.css('.event-team'):
                il = SofascoreItemLoader(selector=row)
                il.add_css('winner' , '.event-team:nth-child(2)::text')
                il.add_css('loser' , '.event-team:nth-child(1)::text')
                il.add_value('date', response.url)

                yield il.load_item()
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Split
from operator import methodcaller
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Selector

class SofascoreItem(scrapy.Item):
    loser = scrapy.Field()
    winner = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()



class SofascoreItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = SofascoreItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(methodcaller('strip'))
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    #review_in = MapCompose(lambda x: x.split("/" , [-1]))
```

Comment: `review_in` input processor has to have a value to split it, right? I don't see where you set its value in `parse` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
il.add_value('date', response.url, re='([^/]+)$')
```

See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html for more details

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It was very simple question "How do I use regex with scrapy item loaders?" like my answer

Comment: @gangabass thanks for your simple answer. Now I understand how regex works with item loaders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is wrong with the code.

Apparently you do not have to 'feed' item loader with `add_value` but you won't get field populated in the end.

```
class SofascoreItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = SofascoreItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(methodcaller('strip'))
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    review_in = MapCompose(lambda x: x.split("/")[-1])
```

You have to do `split` and then select last item in list that is generated by splitting. `split(SEPARATOR, [-1])` is not what you want. Second argument is for selecting in how many parts you want string to be split.

Second, you want to add `url` value to `review` field, right?

This is not an answer how to use `regex` in scrapy `ItemLoader`, but you do not need it here. You just need to properly use `split` method.